# Appended to html page script and CSS don't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to append some CSS and JS to my static HTML file. CSS and JS files are stored in the same folder. It sounds stupid, but I need to do that. So, CSS and JS have been appended but they are not applying to a HTML file because background should be red.
The path that I created is correct because if I do `inspect element` on Chrome Devtools and click to appended link it opens what I need. So, there are no errors, scrip appends what I need, but I see no result.

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

hello world

<script>
  const href = window.location.pathname;
  const chunkIndex = href.lastIndexOf('/');
  const path = href.slice(0, chunkIndex + 1);

  function appendScripts() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = path + "scripts.js";    // use this for linked script
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  function appendCSS() {
    link=document.createElement('link');
    link.href= path + 'styles.css';
    link.rel='rel';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    appendCSS();
    appendScripts();
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS file:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors or double checked the path of the new `css` file is correct and not returning a **404**?

Comment: I've checked, no errors and the path that I created is correct because if I do inspect element on Chrome Devtools and click to appended link it opens what I need.

Comment: Try changing `rel` to `stylesheet` and add `type` with the value of `text/css`. **Example:**  `link.type="text/css"` `link.rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: @NewToJS ooh, thanks so much, it works now!

Comment: You are very welcome. Not sure how I missed that from the first read but I did notice it just after you said no errors in the console and the link is correct :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the following line

```
link.rel='rel';
```

to

```
link.rel='stylesheet';
```

Comment: Sure, whenever your are comfortable. :)

Comment: it's not about comfort. the system of SO doesn't give me to accept any answer so fast because i've just created a question.

Comment: ohh. Sorry my bad. New to SO :(